# Mongo DB - Multi Tenant Environment, Connection Pooling with MongoDB.Driver and Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, connection-pooling, mongodb-.net-driver

I am new to Mongo DB, Need inputs on the below use case.

We are developing a Asp.Net Core API with Mongo DB as the back-end ( multi-tenant application ), We have a collection in master database which holds the mapping between Client ID and the corresponding database.

I am exploring on the below approach at a high level

Create a singleton connection instance for Mongo DB server during service startup and make the instance available to the application via DI ( ConfigureServices in Startup ) And then fetch the appropriate database using the instance via GetDatabase ( MongoDB.Driver ) as needed

1. Will the connection be pooled at a server level ? And when it'll be recycled ?
2. Are there anything to be considered for using Mongo DB clusters
3. Do we need to do anything specific for the closed connection to be re-assigned to pool

I am looking for an approach which would help in performance and scalabality and want to understand how the connection is managed.

Your feedback is greatly appreciated !!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I will be facing the same challenge soon as well